# How to convert llvm IR to c code?

Tags: llvm

Is there any way to convert the llvm IR to c code and keep its semantics? 
For example, can we compile the c code first to llvm IR and then compile it back to another piece of c code. I don't expect that these two files will be the same. But they need to have the same functionality. 
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the C backend, with `llc -march=c`

Comment: It is no longer available in llc-3.4.Is there any alternates?

Comment: @ArunprasadRajkumar, you may be interested in this one: http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2014-August/075875.html