# Is there a "C with classes" language that is not C++?

Tags: c, class, oop, dialect

I'm looking for some kind of C dialect that is as minimalistic as `C` but has built-in classes support. So I can (and encouraged to) use macros, pointers to arrays and manual memory management but also create classes, add fields and member functions to them etc. This question appeared when I tried to implement some kind of OOP in `C` and `typedef struct` and function pointers do something similar to what I want, but "member functions" require to manually pass a pointer to the object as a parameter to them, and that's not what I want to do. I know that I can just write on `C++` as on "C with classes" and I would, however `C++` encourages a different programming style and I'm curious if there is something that is exactly what I want.

I was searching for "C with classes" but I've only seen `C++` in results, so I expect that the answer is "just use C++" and I'm OK with that, but I'm just curious.

Comment: There is also `C#`, which I am reticent to say, I guess qualifies as a type of `C`.  But it is anything but minimalist.

Comment: Related: [Improving a minimalistic OOP for microcontrollers using C, gcc, C99, and Macros with optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909665/improving-a-minimalistic-oop-for-microcontrollers-using-c-gcc-c99-and-macros)

Comment: Check out at least *Objective C*,  *D* and the new *Carbon*, for more insight maybe.

Comment: Re "*C++ encourages a different programming style*", yeah, but you're obviously ignoring that recommendation?! So what's the issue?

Comment: I think D and Carbon are supposed to aim for feature parity with C++, so calling them _"as minimalistic as C"_ seems a bit of a reach

Comment: Nothing prevents you to use C++ like C with classes.

Comment: Carbon is 7 days old! I will definitely check it out. Thanks @hyde

Answer (score 6):

> C++ encourages a different programming style

You can write C++ in whatever style you like. Just choose not to use the features (and libraries) that don't suit your C-with-classes aesthetic.

"C with classes" was originally compiled to C by [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront), but that's extremely dead AFAIK.

I doubt there's much demand for a resurrected Cfront when simply choosing a subset of C++, and using a current C++ compiler, already does everything you actually require.

---

FWIW I have written object-oriented C in the past, and manually passing `this` isn't that much of a burden. Even in Python you have to *declare* the `self` parameter explicitly, and nobody seems upset about that. Having to pass it in explicitly as well isn't so bad.

Comment: So, you have successfully described a language _"...that is not C++"_, but is :-)

Comment: I've previously used _C++ without exceptions_ (for reasons of varying soundness), _C++ without templates_ (on a compiler with terrible template support in the late 90s), _C++ without virtual inheritance_  by default if our class hierarchies are sane ... choosing a suitable subset of the language for the domain is normal practice IME.

Comment: Once you start using C++ you will reach for another feature, and another, and another. And that's a good thing - you'll be using them because you want to